# XML format for IP Ranges in Security Settings

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, security, source

I'm trying to use `sfdx` for source based development. Trying to define the range of whitelisted IPs in `Security.settings-meta.xml`. When I push my code to my org I get an error:

```
Error  force-app/main/default/settings/Security.settings-meta.xml  Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}ipRange invalid at this location in type IpRange
```

Below is an example of how my the relevant XML is structured:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <networkAccess>
      <ipRanges>
        <ipRange>
          <description>example 1</description>
          <end>0.0.0.1</end>
          <start>0.0.0.0</start>
        </ipRange>
        <ipRange>
          <description>example 2</description>
          <end>0.0.1.1</end>
          <start>0.0.1.0</start>
        </ipRange>
      </ipRanges>
    </networkAccess>
</SecuritySettings>
```

I have reviewed the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm) but am still missing something.
How should the `ipRanges` and `ipRange` fields be structured?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the proper format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <networkAccess>
        <ipRanges>
            <description>example 1</description>
            <end>0.0.0.1</end>
            <start>0.0.0.0</start>
        </ipRanges>
        <ipRanges>
            <description>example 2</description>
            <end>0.0.1.1</end>
            <start>0.0.1.0</start>
        </ipRanges>
    </networkAccess>
</SecuritySettings>
```